# Why are load averages on macOS always over 1.0

Tags: macos, unix

My load average on a bunch of Macs running Catalina and Big Sur is always over 1 (1.2 -> 1.5), with just finder open, or safari idle...

On my other linux boxes raspberry pi etc, I usually see close to 0.

Why is a full core always engaged on macOS? is this a BSD thing? i.e. is 1.0 equal to 0 on linux? (or does 1 mean a full core is always used).

Comment: How are you measuring? I’m well under 1 on most machines for top and iostat.

Comment: Can you maybe add a screenshot of Activity Monitor or top ordered by CPU load?

Comment: @nohillside, my top was showing nothing of note, it turns out its a BSD thing: http://undeadly.org/cgi?action=article&sid=20090715034920

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My load averages are routinely 0.29 so we would need to look at your build and details to know why you’re over 1.0.

```
bmike@dev ~ % iostat 10
              disk0       cpu    load average
    KB/t  tps  MB/s  us sy id   1m   5m   15m
   12.20    7  0.08   0  0 99  0.13 0.16 0.18
    5.23    9  0.04   0  0 100  0.11 0.15 0.18
    5.18    2  0.01   0  1 99  0.10 0.15 0.18
    0.00    0  0.00   0  0 100  0.08 0.14 0.17
    0.00    0  0.00   0  0 100  0.07 0.14 0.17
```

The code that became macOS code measures relative task scheduling as opposed to core loading which is different than Linux I suppose. You will want to recalibrate your scripts if you take action upon this measure.

- https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KernelProgramming/Mach/Mach.html
- http://www.undeadly.org/cgi?action=article&sid=20090715034920

Asking why is tough since engineers committed the code and it shipped. Im not entirely sure if this is a BSD thing as much as Mach kernel, but it’s real on macOS.

Comment: Thanks, so I have 3 laptops, intel and new m1 MBP. All show load > 1 (1.3 average) when idle. Interesting.

Comment: I eschew all sync services except for iCloud - many of them can chew energy. Main thing is activity monitor watch for memory pressure and energy use over several hours. You can slim down pretty effectively I find with a little longer term looking. @Woodstock

Comment: You can also just run `top -o cpu` to see the cpu-heavy processes.

Comment: @bmike yep, it seems a load of 1 doesn't mean a core is at 100%